# How to optimize the performance of CefSharp in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, cefsharp

I use CefSharp in WPF and there are delays and stalls when scrolling. Seek ways to optimize performance. CPU: Intel i3 2310 2.1GHz, 4GB RAM, resolution setting: 1920 * 1080, windows7
Thank you

Comment: You can try using the https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-threaded-scrolling command line arg to improve scrolling performance.

Answer (score 2):

For any real time usage of CefSharp you have to use the WinForms version. It is because the WPF version has to render each frame offscreen and then copy it pixel by pixel, basically doing all job in CPU. WinForms renders frames directly in the gpu. One advantage the WPF version has that it can do screenshots of the viewed page, because it already has the rendered image. But if you don't need that, use CefSharp.WinForms.

That does not mean you have to create a WPF project. You still can have a WPF project and use WinForms elements with `WindowsFormsHost`. This has already been proposed here [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549905/1960939).